# Unable to run cameracalibration: module cv2 not found

Tags: python, calibration, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run the camera calibration for my videre stereo camera's.I built the camera calibration package and it did nt give any errors.But when i am trying the camera calibrator node it is givving erors like "no module cv2 found".I tried to find find cv2.so but i found only cv.so.So i commented out import cv2 and just used import cv.Also i changed everywhere in the code where there is cv2 to cv.Now when i am trying to run the node i am getting the following errors.

Exception in thread Thread-4:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner

```
self.run()
```

File "/home/srik/ros/image_pipeline/camera_calibration/nodes/cameracalibrator.py", line 73,

in run

```
self.function(m)
```

File "/home/srik/ros/image_pipeline/camera_calibration/nodes/cameracalibrator.py", line

146, in handle_stereo

```
self.redraw_stereo(drawable)
```

File "/home/srik/ros/image_pipeline/camera_calibration/nodes/cameracalibrator.py", line

292, in redraw_stereo

```
if len(drawable.params) != 0:
```

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

I am stuck at this point.I dont know how to proceed from here.Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.Thanking you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10853/unable-to-run-cameracalibration:-module-cv2-not-found/) by [avin111](https://answers.ros.org/users/56/avin111/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2011-08-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [avin111](https://answers.ros.org/users/56/avin111/) on 2011-08-08**:
I am running ros diamondback on Ubuntu 10.04..

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-08-08**:
Are you running against Diamondback or E-Turtle beta or trunk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like you have mismatched versions of code. The Diamondback version of camera_calibration does an `import cv`, not an `import cv2` (source is [here](https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/image_pipeline/tags/diamondback/camera_calibration/src/camera_calibration/calibrator.py)). However, trunk (i.e. E-Turtle development) does do an `import cv2` (source is [here](https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/image_pipeline/trunk/camera_calibration/src/camera_calibration/calibrator.py)). So if you were running all Diamondback code, there shouldn't have been an `import cv2` in the first place. The rest of your errors likely follow from E-Turtle using a newer version of OpenCV than Diamondback.

Make sure that all of your code is checked out from Diamondback tags or branches and not image_pipeline trunk.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [avin111](https://answers.ros.org/users/56/avin111/) on 2011-08-08**:
Really thanks for the quick reply...It worked.....Thank you